# Is there any way to convert info from txt directly into struct declaration?

Tags: c, struct

I'm currently studying, and one of my colleagues has a project where he needs to read info from a .txt file, and use that info to declare a struct. It's not read info and place it into an already existing struct member, it's literally read the .txt, and "build" the struct with that info (I've never heard of such, and I can't find anything related to this).

So, I'm asking if there's any way to do something like this:

.txt file:

```
struct name{
    member1;
    member2;
}
```

Note: for some reason i had to indent this as code, but it's supposed to be on a txt

C code:
read txt lines
declare struct with it

If you know any way to do this, please answer, cause this doesn't make sense to me, and no one seems to know how to (if possible)

Comment: This would be a method of _auto code generation_, and yes, variations of this are done all the time.  There are IDEs that allow you to use a pallete to place objects that will be part of a user interface, and once the pallet is complete, right clicking it, causes a context menu to appear from which a _Generate Code option can be selected.  [more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming#Source-code_generation)

Comment: Can you post an example of the information in the txt file? In particular, the variability. For example, one text file has names and phone numbers, another text file has street addresses and postal codes.

Comment: _Note: for some reason i had to indent this as code, but it's supposed to be on a txt_.  That is a _feature_ of the editor.  entering 4 spaces in from of a line of text will depict it as code, The `{ }` tool at the top of editor will toggle selected text from normal to code.

Comment: @ryyker I'm not sure I understood what you said, but it's not supposed to be done with the IDE, it's meant to be done within the Code, like, only thing you do is change the .txt, and, by running the program, it'll read the .txt and convert it into a struct definition. If that made sense xD

Also, yeah, I got it, but I had to put the 4 spaces for some reason, i didn't want to

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the txt is not meant to have info. It's meant to be like

struct name{
type member1;
type member2;
}

And we can modify the .txt, to add another member, or change the struct name, etc, but not real info

Comment: @JonasRua but if your txt file already contains the definition of a `struct` where is the *convert* ?

Comment: A C program cannot declare types at run-time, only at compile-time. At compile-time, you could `#include` the text file to define the `struct` type. At run-time the best you can do is construct an abstract data structure representing the type described by the text file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof of concept I used at one point to illustrate a method to create compileable code by running an executable that uses some of its input from  `const char []` variables, and other from `.ini` files all output to new `.c` (and `.m`) file(s) in such a way that to be recognized by a C compiler, and will compile, and another that is recognizable using MATLAB.  These input sources could also be read entirely from a txt file using eg a `while (fgets(...)){...}` construct, which was eventually done in this project.  After this code was generated, the process was followed up with scripting that would compile and execute the new source...

(Note, because not all of the functions used here are defined within this example, consider this a psuedo code example.)

***struct.c***

```
//This application illustrates passing information from
//the configuration tool to a .h file via pointer to struct
// Steps used in this demo:
//  1.  Define struct and sub structs
//         TESST tst
//  2.  Define pointer to BYTE 
//         BYTE *pByte
//  3.  Make all assignments to struct elements using values
//         obtained from reading ini files.
//         tst.x = 13.5;
//         tst.y = 12; ...
//  4.  Set typecasted pointer to byte == pointer to struct
//         (TESST *)pByte = &tst; 
//  5.  Get size of struct
//         sizeS = sizeof(tst);
//  6.  write each byte of tst into data.h
//      in the form of : (eg)
//      BYTE tstChar[64] = { 
//      0x54,0x68,0x69,0x73,0x20,0x69,0x73,0x20,0x61,0x20,0x74,
//      0x65,0x73,0x74,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0b,
//      0x00,0x00,0x00,0x8f,0xc2,0x31,0x41,0x6f,0x00,0x00,
//      0x00,0xde,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x33,0x33,0x53,0x40,0xbc,
//      0x01,0x00,0x00,0x2b,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x33,0x33,0xd3,
//      0x40,0x09,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x3f,0x42,0x0f,0x00,0x00,
//      0x00,0x80,0x3f
//      };
//
//   7. data.h can be used in subsequent .c file in conjunction
//          with struct definition to read the byte data 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int CreateMatlabInitFile(void);

const char include[] = {"#include <windows.h>"};

const char NumSensors[] = { "#define NUM "};

const char *StructString[] = {"typedef struct  {\n" \
                              "     int x;\n"\
                              "     int y;\n"\
                              "     float z;\n"\
                              "} SENS;\n",

                              "typedef struct   {\n" \
                              "     char string[20];\n"\
                              "     int  iNum;\n"\
                              "     float fNum;\n" \
                              "     SENS sens[NUM];\n"\
                              "} Tst;\n" \
                              "typedef Tst TST;\n\n\n\n",

                              "typedef struct   {\n" \
                              "     int x;\n"\
                              "     int y;\n"\
                              "     float z;\n" \
                              "} Tst2;\n" \
                              "typedef Tst2 TST2;\n\n\n\n"};

static char *testChar[] = {"typedef struct {\n\
                            following the continuation character","","",};

const char *MatLabStrings[] = {"init.m",
                               "function [] = init()\n\n"
                               "% These variables are used to initiate the fusion filter\n\n"
                               "global x y z w\n\n"
                               "x = [1 2 3 4 5];\n"
                               "y = [2 3 4 5 6];\n"
                               "z = [3 4 5 6 7];\n"
                               "w = [4 5 6 7 8];\n"
                              };


double ***q;

BYTE *pByte;

typedef struct  {
    int x;
    int y;
    float z;
} SENSOR;

typedef struct  {
    char string[20];
    int  iNum;
    float fNum;
    SENSOR sens[NUM];
} Test;

typedef Test TESST;

const char tstChr[] = {"this is a tst"};

const TESST tesst = {'t','e','s','t',NULL5,\
                         '\0',45,25.223,   \
                         1,2,3.0,4,5,      \
                         6.0,7,8,9.0       \
                    };

TESST tst, tstt; 
TESST *tst2;

int main(void)
{
    int i, len, len1, len2, sizeofString, hexint, intint;
    FILE *fp;
    char projDir[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];
    char fileName[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];
    char buf[2000];

    hexint = 0xff;


    GetProjectDir(projDir);

    sprintf(fileName, "%s\\%s", projDir, "data.h");

    fp = fopen (fileName, "w");

        tesst;

        // Fill tstt (use padding for string data)
        sprintf(tstt.string, "%s", "length == 12");
        for(i=strlen(tstt.string);i<(sizeof(tstt.string)/sizeof(tstt.string[0]));i++)
        {
            tstt.string[i]=0;   
        }   
        tstt.iNum = 11;
        tstt.fNum = 11.11;
        tstt.sens[0].x = 111;
        tstt.sens[0].y = 222;
        tstt.sens[0].z = 3.3;
        tstt.sens[1].x = 444;
        tstt.sens[1].y = 555;
        tstt.sens[1].z = 6.6;
        tstt.sens[2].x = 777;
        tstt.sens[2].y = 999999;
        tstt.sens[2].z = 1.00;

        (TESST *)pByte = &tstt;
        //Fill tst (no padding for strings)
        sprintf(tst.string, "%s", "This is a test");
        tst.iNum = 11;
        tst.fNum = 11.11;
        tst.sens[0].x = 111;
        tst.sens[0].y = 222;
        tst.sens[0].z = 3.3;
        tst.sens[1].x = 444;
        tst.sens[1].y = 555;
        tst.sens[1].z = 6.6;
        tst.sens[2].x = 777;
        tst.sens[2].y = 999999;
        tst.sens[2].z = 1.00;

        (TESST *)pByte = &tst;

        len1 = sizeof(tst);
        sprintf(buf, "%s\n\n", include);
        fputs(buf,fp);
        sprintf(buf, "%s %d\n\n", NumSensors, NUM);
        fputs(buf,fp);
        sprintf(buf, "%s", StructString[0]);
        fputs(buf,fp);
        sprintf(buf, "%s", StructString[1]);
        fputs(buf,fp);
        sprintf(buf, "%s", StructString[2]);
        fputs(buf,fp);
        sprintf(buf, "BYTE tstChar[%d] = { \n", len1);
        fputs(buf,fp);
        for(i=0;i<len1;i++) //package the values of struct "tst" into 
        {                   //byte sized chunks and write out to a file 
            if(i == len1 - 1) sprintf(buf, "0x%02x", pByte[i]);
            else sprintf(buf, "0x%02x,", pByte[i]);   
            fputs(buf, fp);
            if((i%10==0)&&(i != 0))
            {
                fputs("\n",fp); 
            }
        }
        fputs("\n};", fp);

        fclose(fp);

        CreateMatlabInitFile();

        len2 = sizeof(tesst);
        len = strlen(tst.string);
        len2 = strlen(tesst.string);
        sizeofString = sizeof(tst.string)/sizeof(tst.string[0]); //test for a possible loop index for padding string
    return 0;
}

int CreateMatlabInitFile(void)
{
    int i, len, len1, len2, sizeofString;
    FILE *fp;
    char projDir[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];
    char fileName[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];
    char buf[2000];


    GetProjectDir(projDir);

    sprintf(fileName, "%s\\%s", projDir, MatLabStrings[0]);

    fp = fopen (fileName, "w");
    for(i=1;i<sizeof(MatLabStrings)/sizeof(MatLabStrings[0]);i++)
    {
        fputs(MatLabStrings[i],fp);     
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;   
}
```

***data.txt***

```
BYTE tstChar[64] = { 
0x54,0x68,0x69,0x73,0x20,0x69,0x73,0x20,0x61,0x20,0x74,
0x65,0x73,0x74,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0b,
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x8f,0xc2,0x31,0x41,0x6f,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0xde,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x33,0x33,0x53,0x40,0xbc,
0x01,0x00,0x00,0x2b,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x33,0x33,0xd3,
0x40,0x09,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x78,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0x80,0x3f
};
```

***init.m***

```
function [] = init()

% These variables are used to initiate the fusion filter

global x y z w

x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [2 3 4 5 6];
z = [3 4 5 6 7];
w = [4 5 6 7 8];
```

Answer (score 0):

*" the txt is not meant to have info. It's meant to be like struct name{ type member1; type member2; } And we can modify the .txt, to add another member, or change the struct name, etc.*"

I feel this requires a meta-approach. By that I mean that you have a data-structure that can *contain* the structure information and data from the file. The following is an example (it reminds me of working with yacc):

```
#define ELMTYPE_INT 1
#define ELMTYPE_DOUBLE 2
#define ELMTYPE_STRING 3

// Definitions
//
typedef struct T_ELM {          // a data member of a struct
    int elmtype;                    // the base type (see #defines)
    char *elmname;                  // the name of the data member
} tElm;

typedef struct T_ELMLIST {      // a list of elment types
    tElm *elm;                      // the element definition
    struct T_ELMLIST *next;         // next data element
} tElmlist;

typedef struct T_STRUCTTYPE {   // a structure as defined in the text file
    char *structname;               // its name
    tElmlist *elmlist;              // a list of data members in the order defined in the text file
} tStructtype;

// Values
//
typedef struct ELMVAL {         // a value of a data member
    tElm *elmtype;                  // its definition
    union {                         // the value
        int ival;
        double dval;
        char *sval;
    }u;
} tElmval;

typedef struct T_ELMVALS {      // a list of values
    tElmval *elmval;                // its value
    struct T_ELMLIST *next;         // next value
}tElmvals;

typedef struct T_STRUCTVAL {    // a structure variable with values
    tStructtype *structtype;        // its definition
    tElmvals *elmvals;              // its values
};
```